# Failing timer job: User Profile Service Application Proxy - User Profile to SharePoint Full synchronization

Tags: ups

I have a multi tier SP 2013 enterprise farm - 1 app server, 2 wfe, 2 SQL servers in HA mode.
We were having issues with the FIM portion of the UPSS so I stopped the UPSS and am just doing a direct AD import. 
In the last 4 months the User Profile Service Application Proxy - User Profile to SharePoint Full synchronization timer job continually fails.

Can I disable this timer job? What is missing that it keeps failing? The UPSS service on the server is stopped.

My configuration DB has bloated in size because this job has been failing for so long.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This timer job is responsible for pushing profile properties from the UPSA to Site Collections. If you disable it, the Site Collections may have stale information for the User Information List on each one of them.

I would identify why it is failing via ULS logs (setting `Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx` if necessary to get more detail).

In addition, I would look at running `stsadm -o sync -listolddatabases 0` and if any databases are >1 'old', it means the information hasn't been updated properly. If this is the case, run `stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0` (doesn't delete the database, just the sync info). But if that timer job continues to fail, you'll run into the same issue. So look at your logs to help start determine why it is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up. I did review the logs and I see the job start and then end. It times out, but I can't find any reason why. I have tried running it a differnt times to see if it may be affected by other unning jobs but still the same fail notice. I also checked for nay old db's but all are synchonized with the same time stamp.  This job runs on one of my Web front ends while most of the user profile service application jobs run off my app server. not sure why this is set up that way.

Comment: If you can post the log (in it's entirety of the timer job run, not removing any data except to hide what you feel is PII), that may help. Posting it in the original format (not export to CSV) makes it easier to read.

Comment: I decided to focus on reducing the size of my configuration database which had gotten up to 134GB. I found a powershell script that deletes just enough data at a time so that the delete timer job history doesn't fail due to so many entries. Over 5 days I was able to trim the timerjob history table and overall config DB down to 8GB. Now, my User Profile Service Application Proxy - User Profile to SharePoint Full synchronization timer job is no longer failing. your responses to my question were helpful! Thanks Trevor.